# Auto generate an access_token when expired in python or django itself

Tags: python, django, jwt

How can one auto regenerate a refresh_token within a `django admin` app, am using `simple jwt` package, but I want to track if the token has expired then I send a request to auto generate a new `acces_token`, when the session is still on.

Yes I know this can be achieved on the frontend, forexample like in javascript we can use axios interceptors, to auto get another `access_token`, so how can one do this in django it's self.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple middleware that checks if the JWT is valid and if not, can regenerated one. See the middleware docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Ok thanks, for the help